# How to modify moderncvskillmatrix cells?

Tags: moderncv

I am running Debian 10 ("Buster") and texlive.  Trying to use the moderncvskillsmatrix widget, which isn't included in my distro, so I've installed the hacked version from:

https://zhauniarovich.com/post/2021/2021-05-cv-resume/

I much prefer this layout to the "official" one, for the reasons given in the blog.  Unfortunately, it doesn't play nice with my distro; the cells of the table are not well aligned.  Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{moderncvskillmatrix}

\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}

\firstname{foo}
\familyname{bar}

\begin{document}

\section{Skill matrix}

%\setcvskillcolumns[5em][0.8][10em]

\cvskillhead{}

\cvskillentry*{Category}{Skill}{3}{Comment goes here}

%\setcvskilllegendcolumns[5em][0.5]

\cvskilllegend*{}


\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: mwe]

You can see I've tried playing around with the formatting commands (commented out) but they don't really help much.  For example, same script but un-commented:

[image: mwe2]

I gather this has something to do with the blog author's hacks having removed a column from the table, and re-ordered things -- I suppose he has no issues in his LaTeX distro and config.  But unfortunately I don't (yet) know enough TeX to figure out exactly where things are going wrong and hack a solution of my own.

Log for completeness:

https://pastebin.com/85q7htZV

Answer (score 1):

From the `.log` it seems you are running an old version (2015) of `moderncv`

(1) Use the distribution from CTAN [A modern curriculum vitae class](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv?lang=en)

(2) Correct the line `\cvskillentry` (missing number).

(3) Output [image: a]

This is the complete file. The command `\listfiles` at the beginning will add a list of all loaded files and their versions at the end of the `.log` file.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\listfiles
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}    

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}          

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Skill matrix}

%% Usage \cvskillhead[<post_padding>][<Level>][<Skill>][<Years>][<Comment>]%
\cvskillhead[-0.1em]%   this inserts the standard legend in english and adjust padding


%% \cvskillentry[*][<post_padding>]{<skill_cathegory>}{<0-5>}{<skill_name>}{<years_of_experience>}{<comment>}% 

\cvskillentry*{Category}{3}{Skill}{3}{Comment goes here} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

%% Usage \cvskilllegend[*][<post_padding>][<first_level>][<second_level>][<third_level>][<fourth_level>][<fifth_level>]{<name>}
\cvskilllegend*{}

\end{document}
```

At the end of the the `.log` file the listing of loaded files included

```
moderncvheadi.sty    2022-02-21 v2.3.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter header variant: 1
moderncvbodyi.sty    2022-02-21 v2.3.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter body variant: 1
moderncvskillmatrix.sty    2022-02-21 v2.3.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter skill matrix
```

Compiled in a windows machine

```
pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)
entering extended mode
(templatev3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2022-02-21 v2.3.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
```

Comment: Definitely I will be upgrading to Debian 11 (and therefore texlive and moderncv) soon, so that will help.   And learning the `\listfiles` command is very useful.  However, this answer doesn't quite apply to my question because I was asking in the context of the _modified_ version of moderncvskillsmatrix linked in the blog.  Still, upgrading to a new moderncv version might fix the issue regardless, and if so I'll mark this answer correct.  I'll test as soon as I am able.